# Migrate from JWT to Identity Server 4 without need to re-login website users after deployment

Tags: jwt, identityserver4, jwe

I have an API service that is currently secured using **JWT**. I'm going to replace JWT with **Identity Server 4** and secure my API with Identity Server 4. I had a custom way of generating JWT tokens (JWE). How can I replace JWT with Identity Server 4 ***without*** the current signed-in users to the site need to re-login?

Specifically, I wanna use the **Skoruba Identity Server 4** project template.

Answer (score 0):

In IdentityServer, the access tokens are generated to authenticate users. The Access tokens have very small limited lifetime as per convention. There's a concept of refresh token which has longer lifetime and the same is used with basic auth to get new access token. This prevents the hassle to sign in again and again.
The refresh tokens are built using a hash and are persisted in a table (if configured).

JWE is a very different setup altogether. I had my users logged out even after a new deployment of IdentityServer4 (using of persistent grants is helping to solve this).

I don't think it's not technically possible to transfer sessions from one environment to another. Both use a encryption decryption strategies which are very different from each other.

You can give a try by writing a custom implementation of TokenCreationService

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I know the usage of access and refresh tokens, but I was eager to see if there was a way to solve this challenge.

I found a solution at the following link but it didn't work.
https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Encrypting-Identity-Tokens-in-IdentityServer4

Comment: I think I am limited in terms of PKCE discussion to do this, but not sure.

Comment: Also, as you said `I had my users logged out even after a new deployment of IdentityServer4` I think that is because of using developer signing credential.
You can see these two links to solve that problem if still exist:
https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Outsourcing-IdentityServer4-Token-Signing-to-Azure-Key-Vault
https://letienthanh0212.medium.com/identityserver4-for-authentication-and-authorization-with-multiple-instances-using-signing-key-c7cb6f3ea643

Comment: Actually my users were getting logged out because I didn't have persisted grants. My refresh tokens were not persisted in table. I fixed that and its worked wonders!

Comment: Can you tell what exact issue you are facing while following Scott's article?

Comment: Scott's article only tells me how can I inject my own JWE algorithm (Customizing tokens). However, I still could not completely cover my previous JWE algorithm with Scott's method. If you wanna see this I should provide some detailed code. Actually, I'm seeking other parts of the answer to my question (No need to re-login website users after deployment).